# Handling Dependencies Between Bridge Patterns

Tags: c++, image, user-interface, bridge

I'm trying to design a simple board game that supposed to work with different GUI libraries that can be changed during run-time. So the idea is that I want to have multiple classes with each having an image object that represents objects of that class. But since every library chooses to wrap images in classes that are specific to that library, I have to write a bridge hierarchy to abstract any implementation specifics. Something like this

```
class myImageInt{
    // common pure virtual methods that I want my image implementation to define
}

class myImageImpA : myImageInt{
    libAImg img;
    libAImg getLibraryImp(){ return img;}
// provide definition for common interface in terms of libAImg functions
}

class myImageImpB: myImageInt{
    libBImg img;
    libBImg getLibraryImp(){ return img;}
// provide definition for common interface in terms of libBImg functions
}
```

And then I of course will also have to use a bridge hierarchy for the library types that will actually handle the windowing and drawing

```
class myScreenInt{
     void drawImage(myImageInt& img) = 0;
// common methods for drawing onto a window
}

class myScreenImpA : myScreenint{
    libAScreen scrn;
    void drawImage(myImageInt& img){
    // pass the actual library specific object to the libAScreen  so that the image can be drawn
    }
// provide definition for common interface in terms of libAScreen functions
}

class myScreenImpB : myScreenint{
    libBScreen scrn;
   void drawImage(myImageInt& img){
       // pass the actual library specific object to the libBScreen  so that the image can be drawn
   }
// provide definition for common interface in terms of libBScreen functions
}
```

But the problem is that to draw an image onto a window, I’m going to have to call a `drawImage` method on one of the `scrn` objects, and those objects need their actual implementation specific image objects (i.e. libAImg and LibBImg type objects). Is there anyway to be able to achieve this form of library independence without resulting to a type-unsafe `static_cast` or an expensive `dynamic_cast` to cast down the inheritance tree and call a `getLibraryImp` method with a return type that's specific to that implementation?

```
    void myScreenImpA::drawImage(myImageInt& img){
      scrn.drawImage(static_cast<myImageImplA&>(img).getImpl()); //type unsafe cast
   }
```

Comment: Why isn't polymorphism sufficient?  scrn.drawImage(img.getImpl())  Why is the cast required?

Comment: Because each `getImpl` return type would depend on what library its bridging (libAImg or libBImg)

Comment: What are examples of the return type from getImpl?  From the example, it seems it would return a concrete version of myImageInt.  Since drawImage accepts a myImageInt &, all should be well.

Comment: Apologies for the misleading name. I should've named it `getLibraryImpl`, and it should return the image object that is inside the concrete `myImageInt` since the actual `scrn` object only accepts images that are of the corresponding type. Please see the edited question

Comment: getLibaryImpl cannot be a pure virtual if the return type needs to be different on the subclasses.   If it is locally defined on the derived class then a dynamic_cast or static_cast will be required to see and call the method.  Maybe your class hierarchy is not quite right?  Perhaps the screen and image classes should be more closely coupled, like the image instance being a member of the screen?  It seems from your example screenA cannot use imageB so there is no need for loose coupling.  Just some ideas

Comment: I thought about that, but the idea is that am going to have multiple objects with each of them having their own image. How can I achieve this if images are part of the screen classes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179259/discussion-between-matthew-fisher-and-gamefana).

Comment: Can't you do `void myScreenImpA::drawImage(std::shared_ptr<myImageIntA>& img);`  ? For the polymorphism pass by pointer ( not pass by reference) is the way to go. Also object myScreenImpA is to tie up with only myImageIntA, why casting define accordingly? You can also adapt the bridge design into a proxy pattern to simplify the implementation.